# how Do I load a published google-script (webapp) into a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google script in my Google Apps account. The script has been deployed as a web app, and is accessible to "Anyone within yourdomain.com", which is what I want.

problem is how to load the script into a new spreadsheet. I've searched all add-ons by name and filtered by 'For '. Neither yields any results.

Comment: are you sure you don't want a Library instead?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#writingLibrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using add-ons, another way is to use a spreadsheet as your 'template' and call a library with 'wrapper' code in your template's code.gs.
Then, instead of creating a new spreadsheet, make a copy of your template. Use menus to 'install' the script, which will show the oauth prompts that allow to run the script (from menus or created triggers during install).
The library provides a single place to modify the code for all spreadsheets if you add them in 'development mode' to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ons must be approved by Google.

[Google Add Ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish)

Simply publishing your Apps Script doesn't automatically add it to be available as an Add-On.  You can add a link to your published Web App, (Insert, Link) or create a spreadsheet menu that runs a script.

In a Sheet, there is a Tools menu, where you can create an Apps Script that will be linked to your spreadsheet, which is called a container-bound script.

[Scripts and Containers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers)

You can add a custom sidebar to your Sheet, which can contain HTML.

A sidebar can display an HTML service or UI service user interface inside a Google Docs, Forms, or Sheets editor.

[Sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

There is also an import HTML function:

```
=ImportHTML()
```

I think those are your options.